# definition of the set $H(x,y)$

Tags: functional-analysis

In this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584880406), under the section $1.3$ (The Mazur-Ulam theorem), there are some definitions in which I am not clear.

Suppose $X$ is a normed linear space. Let $x,y \in X$. Define the set $$H(x,y)=\lbrace u \in X :||u-x||=||u-y||=\frac{1}{2}||x-y||\rbrace$$ In this case, the author didn't mention what is the norm here. I assume it is the standard norm which measures distance between any two points, i.e. $||x-y||=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$. I try to pluck in example to see what is the set. But i realised that the set contains only one point if I let $x=(0,1)$ and $y=(1,0)$, that is the midpoint of the line segment which joins $x$ and $y$. Is there anything wrong with my intepretation?

Comment: "$X$ is a normed linear space" means that there is some norm on it, which is used to define $H(x,y)$. There is no "standard norm" on $X$ in general. And for your example, $(1,1)$ also appears in $H(x,y)$. In $(\mathbb R^2, \lvert\lvert \cdot \rvert\rvert)$, this set is the perpendicular bisector of the segment joining $x$ to $y$.

Comment: @Antoine: why $(1,1) \in H(x,y)$? I thought $||x-y||=\sqrt{2}$ and $||(1,1)-(1,0)||=1 \neq \sqrt{2}$?

Comment: I beg your pardon, I stopped at $\lvert\lvert u-x\rvert\rvert = \lvert\lvert u-y\rvert\rvert$.. Then you are right about your interpretation for $\mathbb R^2$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interpretation is perfectly fine. A vector space satisfies two obvious algebraic properties concerning vector addition and scalar multiplication, which allow us to build up more machinery with which we may measure distances and compute rotations if necessary. If we have two arbitrary points in our set then we may determine any distance between these two points because these two members of our set may be subtracted from one another (and also added) to form other elements whose distance we may compute using the norm you introduced.